# Dozens of Windows Error Reporting messages each second

Tags: windows-10, event-viewer, windows-error-reporting

I was investigating other problem and suddenly found, that my Event Viewer is full of `Windows Error Reporting` occurring dozens times per second:

[image]

Example of message is:

```
Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: Dev11NonFatalError
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: devenv.exe
P2: 15.0.27130.2036
P3: 5a87a1d8
P4: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Metadata+Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.ComponentInterfaces.IDkmSteppingCodePathProvider:VSDebugEngine.ClrInspector.EntryPoint:GetCodePaths
P5: 15.0.27130.2024
P6: 81255b46
P7: 140
P8: a
P9: System.NotSupportedException
P10: debugger

Attached files:
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERAEDA.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml

These files may be available here:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\NonCritical_devenv.exe_95a7c93d254d8e3665ce6cc8d3ff2d394f6727fb_00000000_1c7a9ca9

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: 3c3ccc3e-f483-41b6-a5bf-13e9bb23aba3
Report Status: 100
Hashed bucket:
```

Many of applications mentionned there, including ones, which are currently running.

Online help on message says error 404.

What are these messages, how harmful are they and how to disable them?

Comment: You get the messages because something is messing up, which is also using resources.  Is your goal to solve the underlying issue or just to suppress the messages?

Comment: @fixer1234 my goal is to understand, what is happening

Comment: I have the same problem on a Windows 10 VM (qemu/kvm). Even the first entry I see in WindowsLogs/Application from 6/7/18 is such an error - so I cannot say if this was already happening before 1803 :/